# CouchDB vs MongoDB for PWA

Tags: nosql, progressive-web-apps

I am starting my first PWA (in Ionic angular). Since I come from an Asp.Net MVC background, where SQL Database is used mainly, I find it hard to decide what is best for me to go with.
There are all these things to be considered with PWA, especially storing data in the device and then syncing with a db and so on. It seems that SQL databases will not do the work for PWA (or are not preferred to).

Everything is pointing towards noSql databases. Therefore I need some tips and personal opinions from experience about CouchDB vs MongoDB (since these are the two I see mostly being suggested and praised).
The focus should be on offline/online storing and syncing between them.
I don't know if I am using the right descriptions and terms but I hope someone will enlighten me and make it clearer what to choose. Other DB alternatives are welcome.

The app will be like a social app for outdoor activities. Users and authentication will be part of it.

Comment: Personal opinions, and thus product recommendations, are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a forum. It's a Q&A site. So a forum wouldn't be like StackOverflow, so no, I don't.

Comment: In any case, I don't have any suggestions for you. Google for MongoDB vs CouchDB, and you'll get thousands of opinions, no doubt.

Comment: StackOverflow has disallowed opinionated questions for over 10 years. This isn't "becoming toxic".

Comment: Yes, that's to be expected. CouchDB and Mongo have been around for many years, and they don't fundamentally change.

Answer (score 2):

As Flimzy points out, this is not the right place for opinions. To address part of your question, Both MongoDb and CouchDb are database servers which would not provide local storage (ie on device) for a PWA. There is a database for this called [IndexedDb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) and this is widely supported by browsers including Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

IndexedDb does not provide a way (that I am aware) to sync with a database on the internet. However you can use [PouchDb](https://pouchdb.com/) which is an interface to IndexedDb. PouchDb provides a facility to store information on the device in IndexedDb when there is no network connection and then sync with CouchDb when there is a connection.

Comment: I have one qustion regarding to PouchDB. In the official website it says "PouchDB is an open-source JavaScript database inspired by Apache CouchDB that is designed to run well within the browser.

PouchDB was created to help web developers build applications that work as well offline as they do online.".

Does that mean (run well within the browser) it will work also for hybrid apps same as for PWA? I mean, the difference in ionic between hybrid and PWA is minimal, you can use the same code to create a hybrid app

Comment: I have not used Ionic, but PouchDb is Javascript so I would expect it to work. I see Nolan Lawson has written an article on the subject, so it would be worth starting there:

https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-ionic

Comment: thank you very much. I have also found two tutorials, for ionic 4 and 5 with offline first in mind. for anyone interested:
https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-sqlite-pouchdb/
https://medium.com/@rajeshpriyadarshinimishra/offline-first-app-using-ionic-pouchdb-couchdb-61ba14cace28